# TLD Cookie Redirect on First Visit Only

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am attempting to redirect a visitor on first visit only IF domain is not correct. All current code is live and can be testing. Here is the current .htaccess that works great for user 1 and NOT for user 2.

```
# Check if the cookie is set on the correct domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !tld=yes [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^MX$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.mx$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://ellasbubbles.mx%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA,CO=tld:yes:.ellasbubbles.mx:/:0:true]
```

User 1: Lives in Mexico, visits ellasbubbles.com and is redirected to ellasbubbles.mx. Then, visits ellasbubbles.com again, and is NOT redirected. **PERFECT**

User 2: Lives in Mexico, visits ellasbubbles.mx and is NOT redirected because domain is already correct. **PERFECT** - BUT - what happens when they try to access ellasbubbles.com: I have set a cookie on ellasbubbles.mx using a cloudflare worker tld=yes. The issue is that the domain is ellasbubbles.mx. Therefore, the htaccess does **not** work. Meaning when the user tries to access ellasbubbles.com. They are redirected back to ellasbubbles.mx on the first try.

Comment: Your description is confusing, I can't tell which exact case is not working as it should. And just FYI, you will probably be creating a redirect loop for users who don't accept cookies here.

Comment: With regards to "User 1" and `.htaccess`, you must have something else that is setting the cookie, since the rule you've posted is "attempting" to set the cookie on the `.mx` TLD, not `.com`. You need to rethink your methodology. You can't determine the users "first visit" to a "series of different domains" using cookie(s).